# How to getItem from local storage in react, while my setItem is working correctly

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

On the first render in React I want to getItem from local storage, but when I refresh the page it's filled again in full. Looking from my localStorage log, setItem seems to be working fine, and changes, but I can't really figure out the getItem. Have in mind that the DUMMY_DATA is an array of objects

```js
const [transactions,setTransactions] = useState(DUMMY_DATA);
    
useEffect(()=>{
    if(localStorage.getItem('transactions') === null){
        localStorage.setItem('transactions',JSON.stringify(transactions))
    }
    else{
        setTransactions(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactions')))
    }
},[])
```

On the first render to have an empty array, no transactions, or the changed array from the state.

Comment: Assuming you don't have `"transactions"` in localStorage (the main `if` branch): is the value in storage being set?

Comment: why not just do as - `const [transactions,setTransactions] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transactions')) || DUMMY_DATA);` ?

Comment: Well @KcH that solved the problem, thank you! (easy solution, because null is falsy, it will skip to the next one.